# How to automatic get data synchronization between a Local/central MySQL server and a multiple remote MySQL servers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, synchronization

We have a scenario where 100 or more remote MySQL local servers are deployed in different parts of the world, they are gathering different data from every place into the same local table and we need a master MySQL server which consolidates all these data and serves the data to the user. The synchronization need to be only uni-directional; only Master needs an update from the remote servers, not the other way around.

The best option will be to automatically synchronize the Master server with either pull or push mechanism whenever there is an update on any of the remote servers, however the synchronization also can be daily. One of the problems is that the local systems can be offline anytime and they are still able to gather data, finally they should upload the data once they got back online.

I'm not sure whether replication will help me here. I just wanted to know whether this requires a custom solution or is there anything that MySQL or any other software provides

Comment: looks like a  custom job  to me - a script to push\pull from each as needed

Comment: I am sorry but I am not expert in databases because of that I am asking, moreover googling is not giving me a simple solution for this

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL supports this natively as defined in this how-to article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this works for multiple slaves and what can happen if they lost connection to the central database, but still are gathering data

Comment: Yes, it should work for multiple slaves. If the central database goes down, they will still retain their data and when the central copy goes back online, they should sync back up.

Comment: I cant understand this at all, I am reading about the master-slave and it states that: The difference between a master server and a slave server is that only the master is permitted to write changes to a replicated database. The slave server will only have read access to it, so for my problem every remote mysql database is a master and the central one is a slave?

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish. Slaves are read-only. Say I have server1. It is the master. Then I have server2 which is a slave. I would use server1 for all my `insert` queries. I could use server1 or server2 for all of my read queries. Everytime server1 has a change (such as an insert or delete) it will notify server2, the slave. Server2 will then update itself based on the notification it received from server2. Slaves take instruction from the master but the slaves can't tell the master what to do. That is why you can only do read queries on a slave. Hope this makes sense!